# Using TouchID on Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use TouchID within my Ionic 2 app and have this simplified code. 
When I run the app on my iPhone I see "A" is logged in the console and then "Fingerprint or device passcode validated."
 but "B" is not logged. What have I missed?

```
checkIn(job) {
    console.log("A");
    TouchID.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint to check in')
    .then(
      res => function() {  
        console.log("B");
      },
      err => alert('Sorry, your fingerprint is not recognised')
    );  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have imported Touch ID Plugin into your project using

```
import { TouchID } from 'ionic-native';
```

In your CheckIn function first check for Touch ID Availability using

```
TouchID.isAvailable()
.then(
  res => console.log('TouchID is available!'),
  err => console.error('TouchID is not available', err)
);
```

If it logs 'TouchID is available!' then in your TouchID.verifyFingerprint function log err to pinpoint the issue

```
TouchID.verifyFingerprint('Scan your fingerprint please')
.then(
  res => console.log('Ok', res),
  err => console.error('Error', err)
);
```

Error Codes

The plugin will reject for various reasons. Your app will most likely need to respond to the cases differently.

Here is a list of some of the error codes:

- -1 - Fingerprint scan failed more than 3 times
- -2 or -128 - User tapped the 'Cancel' button
- -3 - User tapped the 'Enter Passcode' or 'Enter Password' button
- -4 - The scan was cancelled by the system (Home button for example)
- -6 - TouchID is not Available
- -8 - TouchID is locked out from too many tries

Comment: Thank you. Using isAvailable helped me to diagnose what was going on. In the end I needed to run ionic plugin save to update my config.xml and then remove/add the iOS platform.