# The method isAvailable() of TouchID not exists! (ionic 2)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I´m trying to test the TouchID in ionic 2, but its not working.

```
    export class HomePage {

  private touchIdAvailable: boolean;

  constructor(public _navCtrl: NavController, private _platform: Platform) {
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      TouchID.isAvailable().then(
        res => alert('ok'),
        err => alert('not ok')
      );

      this.touchIdAvailable = true;
    })
  }


  private startTouchID() {
    TouchID.verifyFingerprint('Fingerprints are Awesome')
      .then(
        res => alert('Pass'),
        err => alert('Not Pass')
      );
  }
}
```

This code not work. So if I comment this part of code it works!

```
    this._platform.ready().then(() => {
      //TouchID.isAvailable().then(
      //  res => alert('tem'),
      //  err => alert('nao tem')
      //);

      this.touchIdAvailable = true;
    })
```

I get the error: Proprety 'isAvaliable()' does not exist on 'typeof TouchID'

Comment: import { TouchID } from 'ionic-native'; // use this to import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149395/using-touchid-on-ionic-2

Comment: @SandeepSharma, I´m already do this. This is the reason of the second part of the code (startTouchID()) is working. Only TouchID.isAvailable() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found.

In /node_modules/ionic-native/dist/plugins/touchid.d.ts on line 46 I change:

```
isAvailable(): Promise<any>;
```

with this:

```
static isAvailable(): Promise<any>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit `node_modules/ionic-native/dist/plugins/touchid.d.ts`

just initialize `TouchId` instance in constructor.

```
  constructor(
    private touchId: TouchID
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.touchId.isAvailable().then(
        res => this.touchIdAvailable = true,
        err => this.touchIdAvailable = false
      );          
    })
  }
```